# Two lines of code raises internal server error with Gack Id 472275017

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, error, gack

```
<aura:application >  
    <aura:attribute name="cont" type="Contact"/>
    <force:inputField value="{!v.cont.Account}"/>
</aura:application>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create the above application
2. Open it in browser
3. Get the error

[image: Error ID: 1281572413-15971 (472275017)]

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application.
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1281572413-15971 (472275017)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce Support refuses to accept this as a bug.

They also refuse to agree that 'default' parameter is required.

They also refuse to change the error message to "'Default' parameter is required in this context" which I would expect.

Definitely workaround for this works

```
<aura:application >  
    <aura:attribute name="cont" type="Contact"  default="{'sobjectType':'Contact'}"/>
    <force:inputField value="{!v.cont.Account}"/>
</aura:application>
```